# Epson POS printer, ePOS Sdk. What's the default port?

Tags: android, port, epson, network-printers, posprinter

I'm using [TM-T82II](http://www.epson.com.au/pos/products/receiptprinters/DisplayMain.asp?id=tmt82ii) epos printer with the [ePOS-Print SDK](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=4416&pcat=3&scat=50). 
I couldn't figure out how to specify the port on which we need the devices (mobile and printer) to communicate.

What is default port used by the printer/sdk? so that we can enable it on the customised Android on mobile device?

Also, is there's a way to specify the port on which the communication happens.

Comment: Port `9100` is for direct / ESC print, For POS printing the port (in epson at least) is `8008`

Answer (score 1):

In TM-T20II the default port is **9100**. Maybe your printer uses this port.

Comment: Hi, can you help me with the TM-T20II? Do you have a easy print sample (only for this Model and only over usb)?